# Angular: change route when opening sidebar

Tags: angular

I have a list of elements and when I click one of them I display the details on a sidebar (I use `mat-drawer` from Material).

Everything works fine but I'd like to modify the url when I do this so when I refresh the page I'll get this open already.

I've been investigating how to do such thing but can't find the way. I think I could at least modify the url and whenever the user refresh get that url and open the sidebar but I don't know if first approach is possible (it'd be better with normal routing).

```
<mat-drawer-container autosize>
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" position="end">
    <app-partner-details [partner]="activePartner"></app-partner-details>
  </mat-drawer>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="header">
        <app-partners-search></app-partners-search>
      </div>
      <app-partners-list [allPartners$]="allPartners$"></app-partners-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Comment: Could you show some of your code?

Comment: I added some but it's nothing special, just a page with a sidebar with basic info

Comment: when you click on your list elements, you want to call a service or user router.navigateByUrl something like that you mean ?

Comment: The behaviour should be the same: open a sidebar with some content. That's what I have now. The only thing I want to change it's modify the url. If I refresh the page at that point it should refresh with the sidebar open

Comment: hoo. am not sure how you would do that without router.navigate("someUrl"). not sure if there is some way in angular

Comment: I think a proper route won't be possible (unless I'm missing a possible way) so as I mentioned it I could fake it having 2 different routes for the page1. When I open the sidebar I can change the route from page1 to page1/page2. Because page1/page2 also belongs to page1 it won't change anything (I'll just open the sidebar). If I refresh I can check for the url and open again the sidebar

Comment: cool  you  got it.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the second approach I mentioned.

I declared 2 paths for the same page:

```
{
    path: 'partners',
    component: PartnersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: PartnersComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
```

Now when I click to edit, my sidebar opens and I change route:

```
this.drawer.toggle();
        this.router.navigate(['edit/' + partner.id], {
          relativeTo: this.route,
        });
```

I have to change the route back to the original one when I close the sidebar:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.checkRoute();
    this.drawer.closedStart.subscribe(() =>
      this.router.navigate(['/partners'])
    );
  }
```

And also need to check when I refresh that I'm refreshing with the sidebar open:

```
checkRoute() {
    const url = window.location.href;
    const split = url.split('/');
    const id: number = +split[split.length - 1];
    if (id > -1) {
      this.drawer.toggle();
    }
  }
```